# Under what conditions two spaces that are homeomorphic with a point removed are homeomorphic

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I'm trying to state crystal clear that the extended complex plane $\widehat{\mathbb C}$ is homeomorphic to the sphere $S^2$ through the stereographic projection. Of course in this case it easy to see that the two spaces $S^2-(0,0,1)$ and $\mathbb C$ are homeomorphic. But what is the theorem that states that then $S^2$ and $\widehat{\mathbb C}$ are homeomorphic. I know it's a well known theorem but I'd like to have the complete details.

Comment: Have you considered one point compactification?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandroff_extension

Comment: Have you not just written down an explicit homeomorphism using the stereographic projection maps?

Comment: @Tyrone yes I did, I don't have problem there. My point is that the homeomorphism is between the two spaces removing one point (namely the north pole in $s^2$ and infinity in the complex extended palne. I want to know how can I prove that adding these two point the space are necessarely homeomorphic

Comment: I mean write down an explicit homeomorphism between the two spaces without removing a point. It seems like you have correctly defined the maps on all but one point. Can you extend your defintion over the final point?

Comment: @Tyrone You are right, but then I have to be sure of the continuity of the map in that point... so if there was already a theorem it would be already done

Comment: Well, as Baran suggests, you should look up the Alexandroff compactification in a good textbook, as the theory  seems to cover a lot of what you are looking for. My point is that there is exactly one way to extend a homeomorphism between punctured spaces to an injection of sets. Then it only remains to verify the continuity of the resulting map. There is no theorem that can cover the general case, as you can easily verify by constructing explicit examples. In general you will need to check this by hand.

Comment: Do you know that $\widehat{\mathbb C}$ is a compact metric space?

Comment: @PaulFrost I suppose you might know that... if you start from Alexandroff compatification to introduce it, that would be given

Comment: Anyway maybe manually showing the continuity might be interesting even if off-topic. Anyway I'm pretty sure there's a theorem that under some circumstances the homeomorphism stands

Comment: @PaulFrost starting from the Alexandroff compactification you automatically know it's compact by construction. I think you might easily argue that is Hausdorff simply having a look at the topology of the Alexandroff construction. So what is the oneliner in this case?

Comment: Certainly. If you *define* $\widehat{\mathbb C}$  as the Alexandroff compactification of $\mathbb{C}$, then you are done. This comes from the fact that the Alexandroff compactification of a non-compact locally compact Hausorff space is up to homeomorphism uniquely determined as an embedding into a compact Hausdorff space leaving a one-point remainder.

Comment: Is this for the unicity of Alexandroff compatification?

Comment: @PaulFrost Thank you! Can you write it in the answer so that I can upvote it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The extended complex plane $\widehat{\mathbb C}$ is defined by adjoining to $\mathbb C $ an additional point at infinity, that is $\widehat{\mathbb C} = \mathbb C \cup \{ \infty \}$. Algebraic operations are defined in the obvious way. However, this does not automatically provide a topology on $\widehat{\mathbb C}$.

The standard topological model of the extended complex plane $\widehat{\mathbb C}$ is the Riemann sphere  $S^2 \subset \mathbb{R}^3$. In fact, many authors use the stereographic projection $p : S^2 \setminus \{ (0,0,1) \} \to \mathbb C$ to introduce $\widehat{\mathbb C}$. This map is a homeomorphism, and $i = p^{-1}$ embeds $\mathbb C$ as an open subset into $S^2$. Clearly $i$ extends to a bijection $h : \widehat{\mathbb C} \to S^2$ by defining $h(\infty) = (0,0,1)$. Then $h$ induces a unique topology on $\widehat{\mathbb C}$ making $h$ a homeomorphism. With this topology $\widehat{\mathbb C}$ is a compact metrizable space and the subspace $\mathbb C$ receives its original topology.

If you use this construction as the *definition* of $\widehat{\mathbb C}$ as a topological space, then nothing remains to be shown.

On the other hand, it suggests itself to define the space $\widehat{\mathbb C}$ as the Alexandroff compactification of $\mathbb C$. Open neighborhoods of $\infty$ are the complements of compact subsets of $\mathbb C$.

Here are some well-known facts.

(1) The Alexandroff compactification of a space $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space if and only if $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space.

(2) For any two embeddings $i_1: X \to C_1, i_2: X \to C_2$ of a locally compact Hausdorff space $X$ into compact Hausdorff spaces $C_k$ such that $C_k \setminus i_k(X)$ is a one-point set, there exists a unique homeomorphism $g : C_1 \to C_2$ such that $gi_1 = i_2$.

If we apply this to $i : \mathbb C \to S^2$ and $\mathbb C \hookrightarrow \widehat{\mathbb C}$, we get the desired homeomorphism.